# how to group time (format) data in sql

Tags: php, sql

I have a table `depart_timings`. It contains `dept_time`, `station id`, `bus_id`. I want to populate another table `depart_timings_update` and remove duplicate entries. In new table, there is `min_time max_time` and `avg_time` etc. fields.

I use the following query:

```
SELECT * , MIN(dept_time)AS mi, MAX(dept_time) as ma,SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(`dept_time`))) as av FROM depart_timings GROUP BY bus_id,station_id ,HOUR(dept_time)"
```

All are working, but i need to group by `dept_time` in an interval of 3 hours. HOUR(dept_time) this query didn't helps to do it. It separates 11:55:00 and 12:00:00 as separate groups. Please help. Sorry for my bad English.

depart_timings

```
 1 bus_id   int(20) 
2   dept_time   time        
3   station_id  int(20)         
4   user_id     varchar(100) 
5   edit_time   timestamp
```

depart_timings_update

```
1   bus_id  int(20)     
2   station_id  int(20) 
3   min_time    time        
4   max_time    time        
5   avg_time    time        
6   edit_time   timestamp
```

Comment: can you please add sample data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just divide the datetime by 8. Cause you are already converting to hour.

```
SELECT * , MIN(dept_time)AS mi, MAX(dept_time) as ma,SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(`dept_time`))) as av FROM depart_timings GROUP BY bus_id,station_id ,HOUR(dept_time) DIV 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert **dept_time** to seconds and divide it by 10800 seconds (3 hours).

```
SELECT * , MIN(dept_time)AS mi, MAX(dept_time) as ma,
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(`dept_time`))) as av 
    FROM depart_timings 
    GROUP BY bus_id,station_id, TIME_TO_SEC(dept_time) DIV 10800
```

Answer (score 1):

all answers above will have a boundary condition problem .. so i cant use this algorithm .. 
this is my new code

```
        include 'dbConnect.php';
        $que="TRUNCATE TABLE depart_timings_update";
        $r=mysqli_query($con, $que);
     $query="SELECT bus_id,station_id FROM depart_timings GROUP BY bus_id,station_id";
     $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);

     //find bus_id and station_id  uniquely

     while ($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($result))  //for each bus_id-station_id pair
     {
         $bus_id=$row['bus_id'];
         $station_id=$row['station_id'];
         $query="SELECT * FROM depart_timings WHERE bus_id=$bus_id AND station_id=$station_id ORDER BY dept_time";
         $res=mysqli_query($con, $query);
         $i=0;


         while ($ro=  mysqli_fetch_array($res))
         {

             label:
             if($i==0)
             {
                $max=$ro['dept_time'];
                $min=$ro['dept_time'];
                $total=  strtotime($ro['dept_time']);
                $avg=$ro['dept_time'];
                $i++;
             }
            else 
             {

                $m=strtotime($avg);

                $r=  strtotime($ro['dept_time']);

                $di=$r-$m;
                echo $di."<br>";
                $di=  date('H:i:s',$di);
                echo $di."<br>";
                if($di>='06:00:00')  
                    /*if difference is greater than half hour it
                 * treat as another trip of same bus at same route
                 */

                {

                    $q="INSERT INTO depart_timings_update (bus_id,station_id,min_time,max_time,avg_time) VALUES ('$bus_id','$station_id','$min','$max','$avg');";
                    $r=  mysqli_query($con,$q);// depart_timings_update table populates 
                    $i=0;
                    $total=0;
                    goto label;
                }
                if($max<$ro['dept_time'])
                        $max=$ro['dept_time'];
                if($min>$ro['dept_time'])
                        $min=$ro['dept_time'];
                $total=  $total+strtotime($ro['dept_time']);
                $avg=$total/($i+1);

                $avg=date('H:i:s', $avg);
                 $i++;


             }


         }
         $q="INSERT INTO depart_timings_update (bus_id,station_id,min_time,max_time,avg_time) VALUES ('$bus_id','$station_id','$min','$max','$avg');";
         $r=  mysqli_query($con,$q); //populate updated table 
     }
```